# android GridView does not work in my emulator:does not display it though no error is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-adapterview

I tried everything. I tested by copy pasting the example [here from developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) but still didnt do work.  it just shows a blank space whee the gridview was supposed to come.  Here is my code.
**EnterApp.java**

```
package com.locationremind.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EnterApp extends Activity {
    Context con;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        con=this;
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.enterapp);
        GridView gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_menu);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(position==0)
                    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),LocationReminderActivity.class));
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item"+position+"not Allocated yet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }


}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
package com.locationremind.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv;
        /*ImageView imageView;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();*/
        if(convertView==null)
        {    
            tv=new TextView(context);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));

        }
        else
            tv=(TextView)convertView;
        tv.setBackgroundResource(thumbsID[position]);
        tv.setMinimumHeight(128);
        tv.setMinimumWidth(128);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
        tv.setText(text[position]);
        return tv;
    }

    private Integer[] thumbsID={R.drawable.gridview_icon,R.drawable.icn};
    private String[] text={"Select Location Using GPS","Select Location Using Wi-Fi",
                          "Select Location Using Network","Settings"};
}
```

**enterapp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/Rlayout"
     >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:layout_width="64px"
        android:layout_height="64px"
        android:contentDescription="logo-icon"/>
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/grid_menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mistake lies in your adapter as

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

saying you dont have any item to display that is why its not showing any element.

to solve this change your `getCount()` like this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return thumbsID.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getCount returns 0, that's why!

```
  public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return text.lenght;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are value is not coming because in your adapter `getCount()` method is returning 0. put some values on that. or if u put the list as argument in adapter, the u can take that list size as the return for the  getCount().